# find number of running execution of job on wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, java-batch, jberet, jbatch

I use jdbc job repository on wildfly. when I kill wildfly process some job execution remain in started state. When I restated wildfly i get running executions by `BatchRuntime.getJobOperator().getRunningExecutions` and give mentioned job executions. When I use in memory repository it's worked fine.
I want to check number of really running execution.

Comment: What version of WildFly are you running? Instead of killing the process have you trying something like `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c ":shutdown"`?

Answer (score 1):

You should stop running batch job executions first before stopping WildFly or any application server. To clean up batch jobs stuck in running state after killing application server process, you can manually update the job repository database tables.  But this should only be done with great caution so as not to compromise the job repository data.

Comment: Thanks. How can I access to jobRepository?

Comment: You can connect to the database that is configured as the WildFly batch jdbc job repository, using the client tool for the database product (e.g., mysql command or mysql workbench). To find info on batch job repository, you can look at WildFly admin console, or WildFly CLI, or view server.xml.